# in jquery .post need to format json array to html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im newbie at all and learnt to move my old style coding to these.
and now I need helps.

my JSON (array) - result from my php `json_encode`:

```
{"e_id":"12101","e_password":kkkk,"e_secretQuestion":null
{"e_id":"12102","e_password":kkkk,"e_secretQuestion":"abc"}
{"e_id":"12103","e_password":kkkk,"e_secretQuestion":"abc"}
```

my jquery:

```
e.preventDefault();
$.post("/general/helper.php?page=login",$(this).serialize(),function(data,status){          
    if (data != null){
        var tblheader = "<table><tr>";  
        var tblbody= "";    
        $.each(data, function(i, field){
            tblbody = tblbody + "<td style='border:1px solid gray'>" + field + "</td>";
        });
        tblbody = tblheader + tblbody + "</tr></table>";
        $("#hasil").html(tblbody);
    }
},"json");
```

Question:

Its only format onto a table if return 1 row only, but if more rows the table is not formatted...
pls help, how to simply format it to table? at this moment, please don't suggest me to use plugin to format json array to table.

thanks

Comment: I assume the JSON returned actually has the format `{[{"e_id":"12101","e_password":kkkk,"e_secretQuestion":null}, {"e_id":"12102","e_password":kkkk,"e_secretQuestion":"abc"}]}`, right?

Comment: also must be some copy/paste error with `kkk` . I've never seen `json_encode` not double quote properly

Comment: yes, beside i have the proble on parsing JSON syntax, another problem is my JSON format. i thought json_encode do it at once, apparently i must pre format it before encode in my php. anyway, i made success in 3 days (LOL) to make my first PHP, JSON, JQUERY and MySQL CRUD because so long i'm "mi*ro*oft" minded and sticked with VB, ASP and MsSQL. Thank You All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `data` is a parsed JSON array, when your code should look like that:

```
e.preventDefault();
$.post("/general/helper.php?page=login",$(this).serialize(),function(data,status){          
    if (data != null){
        var tblbody = "<table>";    
        $.each(data, function(i, row){
            tblbody += '<tr>';
            $.each(row, function(i, field) {
                tblbody += "<td style='border:1px solid gray'>" + field + "</td>";
            });
            tblbody += '</tr>';
        });
        tblbody += "</table>";
        $("#hasil").html(tblbody);
    }
},"json");
```